# How to change Nim compiler output file location and name

Tags: nim-lang

Compiling a Nim program with `nim c -r example.nim` creates the output file `example`.  I would like to create an output file in another folder with the name `bin/example.o` which is much easier to gitignore.

What I've tried so far:

```
nim c -r example.nim -o:bin/example.o
nim c -r example.nim --out:bin/example.o
nim c -r example.nim -o:example.o
nim c -r example.nim --out:example.o
```

The result of all of these attempts is the same as if I left out the `-o/--out` option, resulting in an executable `example` file in the same folder as the `example.nim` file.  The compiler doesn't even accept the option if I don't pass in the `-r` option (which makes me think I'm misunderstanding the purpose of that option).

I'm using Nim 0.10.3 installed and compiled from the github `devel` branch source.

What compiler option will allow me to modify the compiled output file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is right, but the options have to be before the file you're compiling. You specify `-r` to execute the file after compilation, so it will be run with all the arguments specified after the file.

So this should work:

```
nim c -o:bin/example -r example.nim
nim c -o=bin/example -r example.nim
nim c --out:bin/example -r example.nim
nim c --out=bin/example -r example.nim
```

Comment: This shows in help via `nim --fullhelp | grep '\-\-out:'`.